# Formatting with CSS stylesheet using link tag

Tags: html, css, web

I have issues printing the footer of my website. For some reason, the footer prints correctly, but the link shows up like a normal unformatted link with blue font. What is going on?
The style sheet is included on the page.

```
<div id='footer'>Private Site&copy; <a href='mailto: contact@privsite.com'>Contact Us</a></div>

#footer
{
padding-top: 20px;
border: solid     #4F7D7D;
border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
text-align:center;
display: inline;
}
#footer a:visited,     #footer a:link
{
color:    #666;
text-decoration:none;
}
#footer a:hover
{
color:    #060;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the same color for link, visited and active states, you can make your code a little simpler like:

```
#footer a{
    color:    #666;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#footer a:hover{
    color:#060;
}
```

Also, the order of psudeo-classes for anchor tags is:

**:link** - Unvisited links
**:visited** - Visited links
**:active** - Active links
**:hover** - Links being hovered
**:focus** - Links being focussed on

Comment: The proper order for those anchor pseudo-classes is LVHFA: Lord Vader Hates Furry Animals. (Active should be last because it triggers when the link is being clicked on, which should not be overridden by the hover/focus styles)

Answer (score 0):

Update the line with visited and list with below

```
#footer a:visited,#footer a:link,#footer a
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

```
#footer a:visited,     #footer a:link
```

Shrink these two in two different styles. Or maybe you ignore:

```
#footer a:visited
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your `<link>` tag, which you did not include, or maybe in its character encoding or URL. The problem is not in your markup or in your style sheet, which you included, but outside them. (I mean the technical problem you asked about.)